# Multiple issues in upgrading Grails Project from version Grails 1.3.6 to Grails 2.0.1

Tags: grails, groovy, upgrade

I have upgraded my Grails project from version 1.3.6 to 2.0.1 successfully but whenever I try to run my project via Grails run-app command I face the following issue:

```
Error 2012-04-17 15:44:52,038 [pool-6-thread-1] ERROR [localhost].[/blahblah]  - Error configuring application listen er of
class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.Log4jConfigListener Message:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.Log4jConfigListener    Line |
Method
->>  46 | findClass in org.grails.plugins.tomcat.ParentDelegatingClassLoader |   307 |
loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader |   248 | loadClass in     '' |
303 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync |   138 | run
. . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask |   886 | runTask   in
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker |   908 | run . . . in
'' ^   662 | run       in java.lang.Thread | Error 2012-04-17
15:44:52,116 [pool-6-thread-1] ERROR [localhost].[/blahblah]  -
Skipped installing application liste ners due to previous error(s) |
Error 2012-04-17 15:44:52,117 [pool-6-thread-1] ERROR
core.StandardContext  - Error listenerStart | Error 2012-04-17
15:44:52,120 [pool-6-thread-1] ERROR core.StandardContext  - Context
[/blahblah] startup failed due to previous errors
```

After googling I have found this is a know issue and the work around is suggested here:
[Grails JIRA](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8364?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#issue-tabs)

I have followed the work around but it bring out another issue when I try to run my project, the log is pasted below:

```
Error 2012-04-17 15:59:57,849 [pool-6-thread-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: java.l
ang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/springsecurity/DummyResponse
Message: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/springsecurity/DummyResponse
   Line | Method
->> 736 | invokeBeanDefiningClosure in grails.spring.BeanBuilder
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   569 | beans                     in     '' |   511 | invokeMethod .
. . . . .  in     '' |   303 | innerRun                  in
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync |   138 | run . . . . . . . . . .
. in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask |   886 | runTask
in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker |   908 | run . . .
. . . . . . . . in     '' ^   662 | run                       in
java.lang.Thread

Caused by NoClassDefFoundError:
org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/springsecurity/DummyResponse
->> 169 | forName                   in java.lang.Class

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

|   334 | doCall                    in
SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure2 |   736 |
invokeBeanDefiningClosure in grails.spring.BeanBuilder |   569 | beans
in     '' |   511 | invokeMethod . . . . . .  in     '' |   303 |
innerRun                  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync |
138 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask |
886 | runTask                   in
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker |   908 | run . . . . .
. . . . . . in     '' ^   662 | run                       in
java.lang.Thread

Caused by ClassNotFoundException:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.DummyResponse
->> 202 | run                       in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

|   190 | findClass                 in java.net.URLClassLoader |   307
| loadClass . . . . . . . . in java.lang.ClassLoader |   248 |
loadClass                 in     '' |   169 | forName . . . . . . . .
. in java.lang.Class |   334 | doCall                    in
SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure2 |   736 |
invokeBeanDefiningClosure in grails.spring.BeanBuilder |   569 | beans
in     '' |   511 | invokeMethod . . . . . .  in     '' |   303 |
innerRun                  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync |
138 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask |
886 | runTask                   in
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker |   908 | run . . . . .
. . . . . . in     '' ^   662 | run                       in
java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: From my experience, upgrade from old Grails version to newer is not a reliable process. Sometimes it works out of the box, and sometimes, aven after hours spent on it, it never does. 
If you do not NEED to upgrade, I would suggest you stick to 1.3.6